# How to query the px width of a div 100% width element in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fluid-layout, responsive

I'm new to react and I'm sure I'm not the only one with this question. I have a div in my component that is width:100%; I need to calculate it's pixel width. How would I do this?

To put this in perspective of my actual use-case, here's what I'm doing:
I'm building a slider in react. My slider has a div with the class name "slide-holder" inside of this div are the individual div's for the slides. The slider is  a very basic slider and the slide-holder will move horizontally the width of one slide to change to the next/previous slide.

Here is my full code - be aware I'm still working on this actively so it may break at times but you should be able to get the idea of how it works from it, I'm just doing the basics in react nothing fancy yet.

http://codepen.io/thewebtech/pen/JRXybb?editors=0110

```
    /*var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');*/
var Slide = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div className="slide" style={{backgroundImage:'url(' + this.props.imgsrc + ')'}}>
        <div className="caption">{this.props.children}</div>
      </div>);
  }
});

var SliderControlButton = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    var btnClasses="slider-control-button "+this.props.direction;

    return (
      <button className={btnClasses}>
        {this.props.direction}
      </button>
    );
  }
});

var SliderControls = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="slider-controls">
        <SliderControlButton direction="left"/>         <SliderControlButton direction="right"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
var SliderHolder = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
    var setWidth= React.Children.count(this.props.children)* 200+"px";
    var setSlideWidth= setWidth / React.Children.count(this.props.children);
    return{width: setWidth,
           slideWidth: setSlideWidth

          }


  },
  render:function(){

    return (
    <div className="slide-holder" style={{width: this.state.width}}>
        {this.props.children}
        </div>
    )

  }

});

function renderChildren(props) {
  return React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
    if (child.type === Slide)
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        name: props.name
      })
    else
      return child
  })
}


var Slider = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="slider">
        <SliderControls/>
        <SliderHolder>
            <Slide imgsrc="http://jonmclarendesigns.com/wedding/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/DSC_4050.jpg">hello</Slide>
          <Slide imgsrc="http://jonmclarendesigns.com/wedding/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/DSC_3819.jpg"/>
        </SliderHolder>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Slider/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm not actually answering your question directly, but I think for the actual usecase you've described, you'd be better off using some prebuilt tools.

[react-css-transition-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-css-transition-replace) solves this exact problem.  All you need to do is apply CSS transition classes and render the desired slide component.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing me to that resource it will come in handy if I end up adding the ability to make it do fades and other transitions, but it seems like doing this to fake the sliding effect is actually more complicated than doing it the way I was referring to.

Comment: CSS's `translate` property handles sliding perfectly.  Feel free to disregard if you want to home-grow a solution, but I really would encourage using this package.  It's generally a good idea to manage transitions and animations in CSS when possible, rather than doing them in javascript.